# JSF2: Handling Data between ManagedBeans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am confronted with a problem I don't find an easy suificiant way:

I use different ManagedBeans to organise my views. There are controller that manage actions and passes data from/to persistence layer. Further there are models that lie behind the views and contain their data.

Controller which are RequestScoped initialise the model (-managedBean) and fills it with data. Model (-managedBeans) are SessionScoped. That worked well so far.

**But how can I pass data between two requestScoped controllers?**

My Controller initialises the model and when I want to work with data it is always gone because with any request data in my models are refilled by empty objects.

---

I would like to **extend my question**: I'm doing it like Bozho posted it already. But my 'anotherBean' (like he called it) is null after some times? Does JSF recreates beans for some reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ManagedProperty(name = "#{anotherBean}")
private AnotherBean anotherBean;
```

Comment: @Bozho, Do we have any similar solution for JSF 1.2 version?

Comment: yes, integrate jsf with spring. It's easy - as far as I remember you just need to configure a spring resolver in faces-config.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the requestscope `Map` through the `FacesContext` envorinment.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap()
```

There you have a Map where the string is the managed bean name and the Object is the instance of the managed bean.

I'd recommend you [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) about communication in JSF, written by BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, but my mistake has been somewhere else.

A few weeks ago I tried to integrate PrimeFaces for testing purposes. I didn't get it working and removed it. But I forgot to remove the dependency in my pom file (for maven). After removing PrimeFaces from my pom file, my webapp works fluently.

Answer (score -1):

use ViewScoped for ManagedBean instead of RequsetScope

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I asked for. And I don't want to drop my structure only because it works then -.-